# Go Gin-Gonic Handle Not Found for Route Group

Tags: go, routes, go-gin

I was wondering how to get a Go Gin-Gonic Web Server to handle Not Found Routes for a specific Group. If I have the following Code :

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    // handle /sub routes

    rGroup := r.Group("/sub")
    {
        rGroup.GET("/a", func(c *gin.Context) {
            // respond found /sub/a
        })

        rGroup.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) { // this fails, NoRoute is not available
            // respond not found in /sub
        })
    }

    // handle / routes

    r.GET("/a", func(c *gin.Context) {
        // respond found /a
    })

    r.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
        // respond not found in /
    })

    r.Run(":8000")
}
```

Then it is working for the `/` routes but the Group does not have the `NoRoute` Method so is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Gin does support this. Inside the NoRoute, You can do different logic based the gin.Context and return different results.
```

After conducting some research, it appears that Gin currently does not support this directly. Instead, it can be achieved in a different way using `NoRoute`

Here is a sample implementation; I hope this helps.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func notFoundHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    // check the path is /sub
    if strings.HasPrefix(c.Request.URL.Path, "/sub/") {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Route not found in /sub"})
        c.Abort()
    }

    // check the path is /v1
    if strings.HasPrefix(c.Request.URL.Path, "/v1/") {
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Route not found in /v1"})
        c.Abort()
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    v1 := r.Group("/v1")
    {

        v1.GET("/a", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{"message": "inside v1 a"})
            return
        })

    }

    rGroup := r.Group("/sub")
    {

        rGroup.GET("/a", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{"message": "inside sub a"})
            return
        })

    }
    r.NoRoute(notFoundHandler)

    r.Run(":8000")
}
```

Reference :

- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/2999
- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1157

Comment: A bit weird how it can only be handled separately from the Router Group itself (potential for annoying bugs) but this works for my needs, thanks so much!